# Can't find array value

Tags: java, arrays

Can someone help me with this problem.

I have been given to do some coding exercise

I need to do search Array problem
Below is the output that i want :
[image: Output that i want]

I have a problem where when I put the correct value it will not come out the output I want instead it will come out the output "Player not Found" so how to solve this. I feel like I missed something.

Here my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[]args){
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
       
       System.out.println(" Welcome to VictoRoar Information System " );
       System.out.println( " ********************");
       
       System.out.print(" Enter n , number of player: ");
       int n = sc.nextInt();
       //declare,initialize array 
       String [] name = new String[n];
       double [] height = new double[n];
       sc.nextLine();
       
       //put input in the array 
       for (int i=0; i<n;i++)
       {
       System.out.print(" Enter player's name :" );
       name[i] = sc.nextLine();
       System.out.print(" Enter player's height (cm) :" );
       height[i] = sc.nextLine();
       }
       
       //search array
       System.out.print(" Write the player height that you want to know : ");
       double findheight=sc.nextDouble();
       boolean noheight = false;
        for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
       { 
          if (n == height[i])
       {
          noheight = true;
          System.out.println("Player name "+ name[i] + " with height " + height[i]+ " present at index " +i);
       }
       }
          if (noheight == false ) 
       System.out.println("Player not found");
       System.out.println("**********************");
    } 
}
```

I hope you guys can help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. As a refresher, please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `findheight` instead of `n` variable in your `if (n == height[i])` condition:

try this it's work :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println(" Welcome to VictoRoar Information System " );
        System.out.println( " ********************");

        System.out.print(" Enter n , number of player: ");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        //declare,initialize array 
        String [] name = new String[n];
        double [] height = new double[n];
        sc.nextLine();

        //put input in the array 
        for (int i=0; i<n;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(" Enter player's name :" );
            name[i] = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.print(" Enter player's height (cm) :" );
            height[i] = Double.valueOf(sc.nextLine());
        }

        //search array
        System.out.print(" Write the player height that you want to know : ");
        double findheight=sc.nextDouble();
        boolean noheight = false;
        for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        { 
            if (findheight == height[i])
            {
                noheight = true;
                System.out.println("Player name "+ name[i] + " with height " + height[i]+ " present at index " +i);
            }
        }
        if (noheight == false ) 
            System.out.println("Player not found");
        System.out.println("**********************");
    } 
}
```

result:

```
Welcome to VictoRoar Information System 
********************
Enter n , number of player: 2
Enter player's name :Alex
Enter player's height (cm) :120
Enter player's name :David
Enter player's height (cm) :122
Write the player height that you want to know : 120
Player name Alex with height 120.0 present at index 0
**********************
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i know it i missed something. now i get it. thank you so much @MedElgarnaoui. Already tested it.